# Convergence of a sequence with natural logs

Tags: convergence-divergence, logarithms

Let $c>1$ be an integer constant.

Edit: I am wondering if the sequence
$$
cn\left[\frac{1}{\ln\left(n\right)} - \frac{1}{\ln\left(c n\right)}\right]
\qquad
\mbox{converges as}\quad n \to \infty.
$$
My first guess is that it should go to $0$, but simulation results show otherwise.

Comment: That's $\log c/(\log n \log (cn))$ so indeed it converges to $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Response to the **updated** question....

Notice that

\begin{align}
cn \left(\frac 1 {\log n} - \frac 1 {\log cn}\right) 
&= \frac{cn \log c}{(\log n)(\log n + \log c)}.
\end{align}

Now $\log(n)^2$ is far smaller than $n$ once $n$ is large enough, so this tends to infinity. This almost grows linearly in $n$.

Comment: Thanks, good explanation. I realized the extra bit was crucial.

Comment: So this would be O(n)?

Comment: Yes, but it's $O(n)$ without the logs too.... and that doesn't imply that the limit is infinite.